# AngularJs use service from another module

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use a service from my main module that I'm going to use everywhere.

This is my **controller** where I would like to use it:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.page')
    .controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location','requestService', authCtrl]);


    function authCtrl($scope, $window, $location, requestService) {
        $scope.login = function() {
            requestService.test();
        }
    }
})();
```

**module**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.page',['app']);
})();
```

**Service**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .service('requestService',requestService);

    function requestService() {
        this.test = function()
        {
            alert('test');
        }
    }
})();
```

But the `requestService()` is not found in my `controller`. What am I doing wrong here?

--EDIT--

error message:

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=requestServiceProvider%20%3C-%20requestService%20%3C-%20authCtrl
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:7
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:69
    at d (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at e (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:1)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:86)
    at S.instance (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:88:235)
    at n (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:64:174) <section data-ui-view="" class="view-container {{main.pageTransition.class}} ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

Comment: what is the question & problem?

Comment: Where is the definition of the app module? And what is the exact and complete error message you get? This is critical information.

Comment: @JBNizet I've added the error message.

Comment: You should not use the minified version of angular when developing. The error messages would be much clearer with the non-minified version. You still haven't told where the app module was defined. But my guess is simply that you forgot to include the script file containing the service in your HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS access service from different module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966858/angularjs-access-service-from-different-module)

Answer (score 0):

When you defined your service module you didn't provide an empty dependency array to create a new module. Angular will try to find an existing `app` module and not find it. You need to define your service module like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [])
        .service('requestService',requestService);

    function requestService() {
        this.test = function()
        {
            alert('test');
        }
    }
})();
```