# AngularJS controller dont work after adding a service as dependency

Tags: angularjs

hello i'm working on my small project using angular , during the creating my second controller with second service i have a problem , when i inject my own service as a dependency in the controller it dont work and all of expressions in html file are not resolved (before adding a service all works) here is my code

after adding AccSrv to AccCtrl the problem occurs

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'membersService']).config(
    ['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'MembersCtrl'
        }).when('/account', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/account.html',
            controller: 'AccCtrl'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }]);
```

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>myApp</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/MemberSrv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/MemberCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/AccSrv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/AccCtrl.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AccCtrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>{{hello}}</p>
<p>{{world}}</p>
<form name="accForm" ng-submit="createAccount()">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ng-bind="newAccount.email"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-bind="newAccount.password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="registerAccount" value="Sign-up"/>
    </div>
</form>

<form name="accForm" ng-submit="getAccountByEmail()">
    <div>
        <label for="getemail">CheckEmail</label>
        <input type="text" name="getemail" id="getemail" ng-bind="ExistingAccount.email"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="check" value="Check"/>
    </div>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ExistingAccount.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ExistingAccount.email}}</td>
        <td>{{ExistingAccount.password}}</td>
        <td>{{ExistingAccount.creationDate}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```js
angular.module('AccountService', []).service('AccSrv', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.getAccountByEmail = function (email) {
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/gadziksy-web/rest/account/" + email
        };
        return $http(req);
    };
}]);
```

---

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('AccCtrl',['$scope','$http' ,'AccSrv' , function ($scope , $http , AccSrv) {
    $scope.hello = 'hello';
    $scope.world = 'world';
    $scope.ExistingAccount = {
        "id": '',
        "email": '',
        "password": '',
        "creationDate": ''
    };

    $scope.getAccount = function () {
        return AccSrv.getAccountByEmail($scope.ExistingAccount.email).then(function (data) {
            $scope.ExistingAccount = data.data;
        })

    }
}]);
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message you receive when visiting the page that loads that controller?  To see the error message, right click and click inspect (if you're on Chrome)

Comment: you need to include AccountService module into your app module. Your service is defined in different module than 'myApp'. Here is another link which explains it  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966858/angularjs-access-service-from-different-module`

Comment: thank you for answer it was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your service is being defined in a module that you are not including anywhere:

```
angular.module('AccountService', []).service('AccSrv'...etc
```

should be

```
myApp.service('AccSrv'...etc
```

Otherwise you will need to include the AccountService MODULE as a dependency of myApp.

Answer (score 0):

@yBrodsky is correct you need to change

```
angular.module('AccountService', []).service('AccSrv', ['$http', function ($http) {
```

To:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('AccSrv', ['$http', function ($http) {
```