# AngularJS module architecture - in the middle of two approaches

Tags: angularjs, module, architecture

I went deep into investigating of modern approaches and stuck with a problem.

One approach is to split application modules depending on purpose:

```
angular.module('controllers', [])
angular.module('directives', [])
angular.module('services', [])
```

Another approach is to split modules by feature

```
angular.module('page.user', [])
.controller()
.service()
```

I do like the second one and believe that is the most efficient one. BUT, what about reusable services? Here is a brief example I took from my head:

```
angular
    .module('myApp') // myApp refers to the main app module
    .service('userService', function($http) {
        let self = this;

        self.getUser = function(id) {
            return $http.get('api/user/' + id)
            .then(functions() {
                // some important logic hoes here
            })
        }
})
```

So I have a `getUser` method, that contains some specific business logic.
I do not want copy the same method to every new feature-module because DRY. I want every feature, that need `getUser` ,method to refer `userService`, so in this case I would need to put the service into main app module which will bootstrap all other feature-modules as well, or I need to create a modules specially for shared services and now we at the first `on purpose` approach.

So the question is more like how to stick to the second approach and keep everything well organized with DRY principle. Thanks

Comment: This is depending on your requirements / specs. So please write down your full software requirements. In that way we could give an "advice" what would be the best way to structure your software.

Comment: [This blog](https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw/building-large-apps-with-angularjs) suggest monolithic folders organised **by feature** for **big** apps

Comment: @lin Can you please specify what exactly do you mean by `full software requirements`

Comment: E.g. do you need to split it into modules because it does effect your build process. E.g. if you want to build different applications based on your sourcecode which are including only a specific stack of modules. IMO splitting your components (controllers, factories, services, components.. etc.) into own modules doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: If you have different modules in your application like `angular.module('base', [])`, `angular.module('userPanel', [])`, `angular.module('configurationPanel', [])`, , `angular.module('statisticPanel', [])` this whould make sense. But I would preffer to build components instead of own modules.

Comment: @lin So I already have a huge app with huge number of shared services and only one module, right now I want to start using components instead of controllers and it seems great to have one module per component, but some components may need to call the same `getUser` method and I do not want to copy this method through all components

Comment: There is no limitation. You can use services, factrories, components, directives based on e.g. Module1 also in Module2. You don't need to copy them -> you have to inject them. This is a simple example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966858/angularjs-access-service-from-different-module

Comment: You will have hard time justifying the first approach, because it doesn't make sense to differentiate these units on module level, design-wise. *BUT, what about reusable services?* - you don't want to make *all* services reusable, so `services` module won't help. You likely want some of them. That's what `common` or `shared` module is for. You can make modules as fine-grained as you want. If you feel that `userService` can be reused apart from other reusable services, move it to its own module.

Comment: There is no need in putting each component to own module as well as you do not put each class in own package in Java. Also notice that there is no framework (at least I dont know one) that do it.

Comment: so when I started writing tests it turns out that testing each module independently gives better performance and avoiding undesirable interaction with other application

Comment: It feels like I get what I wanted, I will stick to @lin and @estus suggestion, e.g. put `userService` into user module, and putting some re-usable services like pop-up or form service into common module